# Traversing multiple symbolic links recursively in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, symlink-traversal, readlink

I want to write a recursive function to traverse symbolic links from source path  to destination path

Example:
1)readlink patha/pathb/pathc -> gives  if symbolic link exists
2)readlink patha/pathb/pathc/ -> gives  if symbolic link exists

I'm using os.readlink method in python to get symbolic link in Python but how to traverse multiple symbolic links

Reason for traverse:
If its in future someone wants to add file3 symbolic link in between , then I wanted a recursive function to traverse each symbolic links and gives the final dest path
file1 -> file2 -> .... -> for getting destination path

Comment: Your example is not enough to induce what you want to do.

Comment: Yes I have added precisely what I wanted to do.

Comment: I hope  now the problem is clear. Thanks

Comment: Hehe .No I corrected it now.

Comment: @Somu Dose it solve your question?

Comment: Ya this solution worked out and solved me the problem of traversing symbolic links from any path recursively.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use

```py
import os

def find_link(path):
   try:
        link = os.readlink(path)
        return find_link(link)
   except OSError: # if the last is not symbolic file will throw OSError
        return path

print(find_link("a/b/c"))
```

Comment: Ya this solution worked out and solved me the problem of traversing symbolic links from any path recursively.Thanks

Comment: @Somu You could mark this to be the answer, that will help others who have the same question in the future.

Comment: @ Epic Chen Yes I marked this as answer .Thanks

Comment: Glad to be of help.